# Middleware not executed depending on order

Tags: c#, .net-core, middleware

I understand that the middlewares are injected in-between and surrounded by the preceding ditto. At the course of each, we can invoke a call to `next()` and pass the baton to the succeeding, inwards ware. By that logic, the order might affect the behavior of the application. However, I can't see how the order might cause the chain to be broken (unless an exception occurs or a developer fails to invoke `next()`).

I noticed that the following order (vanilla weather project) does execute both middlewares.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => throw new Exception());
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
```

When I switch the order, as below, only `UseEndPoints(...)` is executed while `Use(...)` never happens (according to a bunch of breakpoints not hit and even an exception not being thrown).

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
app.Use(async (context, next) => throw new Exception());
```

I have found [some info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-3.1#accept-websocket-requests-1) relating to web sockets saying something about an error if the pipeline has run out. However, this doesn't produce the mentioned error and doesn't really invokes web sockets in my vanilla project. So I sense I'm missing something else.

> ...you must keep the middleware pipeline running for the duration of the connection. If you attempt to send or receive a WebSocket message after the middleware pipeline ends, you may get an exception...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is mentioned in your question: "a developer fails to invoke next()", although in this case it’s not a failure as such, as that middleware is essentially the end of the pipeline, if it finds an action to execute.

See the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointMiddleware.cs).

Comment: On one hand, it makes sense that once an endpoint is recognize, the baton pass gets terminated. However, it seems to me so intuitively appropriate that the "rings of hell" should be passed down to the innermost level making the journey finalized only when there's no else tier to invoke. Or, at least, mark such middlewares like `UseEndpointsAndPossiblyTerminate(...)`.